# How to return the difference between two column values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables when there are 2 columns. The first column is the start time work shop. The second column is the hour of the completion of the work shop.

Examples:

```
id | start | stop
1  |    10 | 18
2  |     8 | 20
3  |    11 | 21
```

I need a list of stores that are now working.

```
Now hour = 10
start >= '".$now_hour."' and stop <= '".$now_hour."'
```

I see only shop `id=1`, but shop `id=2` also should be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `between` clause with your value on `nowHour`

```
where ? between start and stop
```

`?` is place holder for `nowHour` value.
Use prepared statement in your scripting language to bind the placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Logic is incorrect?

```
`start` <= '".$now_hour."' and `stop` >= '".$now_hour."'
```